# ansible problem execut for get vm info in vsphere

Tags: python, ansible, virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere

I try to execute this ansible yml file to get vm info in vsphere,

I have two files:

hosts file:

```
[Web]
192.168.11.11 #ip of my vsphere server
```

test.vmware2.yaml file:

```
- name: Gather all registered virtual machines
  community.vmware.vmware_vm_info:
    hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
    username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
    password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: vminfo
```

I execute with this command:

```
ansible -i /mnt/hosts test.vmware2.yaml
```

I have this message:

```
ERROR! 'community.vmware.vmware_vm_info' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in '/mnt/test.vmware2.yaml': line 1, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Gather all registered virtual machines
  ^ here
```

I want to know what is the problem ?

thanks for your response

Comment: maybe you can put here the ansible version you use? `ansible --version`

Comment: Is that all you have in `test.vmware2.yaml`?

Comment: i have this version of ansible ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/gthuraisingam/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]

Comment: its that all i have in the file [test.vmware2.yaml]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to execute an ansible-playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i /mnt/hosts test.vmware2.yaml
```

then you playbook file should look like this:

```
 - hosts: Web
   gather_facts: false
   become: false
   vars:
      vcenter_hostname: 10.10.10.1
      vcenter_username: user
      vcenter_password: password
   tasks:
     - name: Gather all registered virtual machines
       community.vmware.vmware_vm_info:
         hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
         username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
         password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
       delegate_to: localhost
       register: vminfo

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.guest_name }}, {{ item.ip_address }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ vminfo.virtual_machines }}"
```

Comment: i execut this but i have this message :[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: Web

PLAY [Web] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP *************

Comment: is the `/mnt/hosts` contains the group `[Web]`? you also can use `localhost` as host, since you're delegating the task to `localhost`

Comment: how can i use that, i try to execute since my computer 192.168.10.10 and my target is get information since vsphere 192.168.11.11

Comment: how about `ansible-playbook playbook.yml` and change the hosts from `Web` to `localhost`, like this `- hosts: localhost`

Comment: i change  Web to localhost in the fie test.vmware2.yaml but now i have this error message: 
TASK [Gather all registered virtual machines] **********************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'vcenter_hostname' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/mnt/test.vmware2.yaml': line 5, column 8, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n   tasks:\n     - name: Gather all registered virtual machines\n       ^ here\n"}

Comment: yes you need to declare the variable you pass to your tasks, it can be done in the inventory level (group_vars) or in your playbook, to add a new option called `vars` and it a list of your variables, I'll update my post up for an exmple

Comment: now i have this message:ASK [Gather all registered virtual machines] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to connect to vCenter or ESXi API at 192.168.11.11 on TCP/443: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)"}

Comment: add `validate_certs : false` to the task options

Comment: i think its ok i'me connected, i have this message : PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gather all registered virtual machines] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost -> localhost]

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************

Comment: i want to know how to list all vm with ip please

Comment: you need to print the registered variable, I'll update the code up

Comment: that work :) , is it possible to have only guest_name and ip_address ?

Comment: i have this message : TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'vm_info' is undefined"}

Comment: i have many information, it possible to have only 'guest_name' and 'ip_address'  like a list please ?

Comment: did you check my post? it should only print 2 attributes

Comment: i see your post but that print many information like  'guest_fullname',  'power_state', 'mac_address', 'ip_address', 'uuid' and more

Comment: maybe you can put here the full output

Comment: i commented this line msg: "{{ item.guest_name }}, {{ item.ip_address }}" and i have the same result, i think this line is not taken